# Footer not aligning below main content in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to responsively lay out a bunch of images.

```
.cards
  .card.card1
  .card.card2
  .card.card3
  .card.card4
   etc....
footer
```

css:

```
 .cards{
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   height: 81.2rem;
}

 .card{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   height: 100%;
   max-height: 28rem;
   position: relative;
 }
```

The problem I'm having is...

I have a footer that needs to be below the `.cards` div, but since `.cards` has a height, the footer is hovering over the div where I tell the height to be. (The cards themselves extend past the height.)

I have tried setting a taller height, however, then the space between the rows of cards expand (which I don't want).  I've also tried not setting a height, but then the cards don't lay out at all, they just disappear or float way down the page.

Is there a way I can clear the `.cards` div?

Or just in general, get the footer to appear below the cards?

This shows the footer where it currently is, which is incorrect.

[image: footer in wrong position]

This shows the footer where I need it to be:

[image]

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle? It's hard to figure out exactly what's wrong with the given code.

Comment: talk about a nightmare, my css is doing too much to simplify

Comment: How do you think we feel then? Haha

Comment: I know, but I tried, it's going to take forever, I have a lot of responsive styles that are all done in sass.  it's makes reading the css impossible

Comment: but nothing comes to mind?  I feel like this is kind of default flex box behavior

Comment: Instead of `height: 100%`, which limits the container to a fixed height, use `min-height: 100%` or remove `height` altogether. If your `height` property is installed properly, you may need to apply the `min-height` to parent or ancestor elements.

Comment: I think michael_B is right.  it definitely has to do with the height.  I think I was stuck on an old css principle where I would set the height of a div to 100% and then limit the height of the div with a max-height property.

in the end, I removed the height of the .cards div and set a height on the individual .card elements themselves

thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `height: 100%`, which limits the container to a fixed height, use `min-height: 100%` or remove height altogether.

If your `height` property is [installed properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276), you may need to apply the `min-height` to parent or ancestor elements.

More details: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

---

***Additional notes from OP:***

> Add the height to the direct children of the flex-box, this allows the container to determine its height.
>
> On another note, if you put the height on the sub-children (not direct descendants), the container flex-box will not know how to set its own size and will have no height.